# How to fix this JS into TS?

Tags: typescript

```
{ for (var i: number = 0; i < selectedProfile.length; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 2) {
      <div className="sliderContainer">
    }
  } 
}
```

> An arithmetic operand must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2356). A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.

How can I fix this this? Error happening on the first line?

Interface definition of a object in that array would be the following:

```
export interface ILinkedInProfile { 
  postContent: string; 
  postUrl: string; 
  profileUrl: string; 
  action: string; 
  imgUrl: string; 
  likeCount: number; 
  companyName: string; 
}
```

Comment: `let i: number = 0` Maybe?

Comment: Still no working :(

Comment: What's the type and content of `selectedProfile` is it an array?

Comment: export interface ILinkedInProfile {
    postContent: string;
    postUrl: string;
    profileUrl: string;
    action: string;
    imgUrl: string;
    likeCount: number;
    companyName: string;
} Thats the interface for the type for the objects in the array

Comment: So I'm wondering about the outer curly braces and the return of a div inside the if statement. Are you using this piece of code inside a React component?

Comment: BennKingy, please [edit] your post instead of adding comments. Having tried something for 20 minutes doesn't really seem like a huge amount of investigating was part of this? did you check what the error means? Why are you not using `map` instead, or even filter and then map?

Comment: `selectedProfile` is an object not an array, right?

Comment: @AliShahbaz correct. And r3dst0rm you are correct also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Property 'length' does not exist on the type of Object.

You can try `Object.keys(selectedProfile).length` to get it's length